# Joining 3 tables referencing table 1 and combining values with comma delimiter in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble on joining three tables.
First attempt on joining two tables is success, but on third table the results are not correct...

I have three tables **machine_list** is *mainTable* then **applicable_rpm** and **applicable_product** are some details of *machine_list*

Table: **machine_list**

```
| id | machine_number | machine_brand |
---------------------------------------
| 1  |     MN-1       |     TOYO      |
| 2  |     MN-2       |    AMITA      |
```

Table: **applicable_rpm**

```
| id | mc_recordID | rpm |
--------------------------
| 1  |      1      | 20  |
| 2  |      2      | 20  |
| 3  |      2      | 25  |
```

Table: **applicable_product**

```
| id | mc_recordID | productline|
---------------------------------
| 1  |      1      |    mono    |
| 2  |      2      |    mono    |
| 3  |      2      |    poly    |
```

I want to return like this:

```
| machine_number |   rpm  |   twine    |
----------------------------------------
|      MN-1      | 20     | mono       |
|      MN-2      | 20, 25 | mono, poly |
```

I first try joining the two table with this query:

```
SELECT t1.machine_number, GROUP_CONCAT(' ', t2.speed) machine_speed
FROM machine_list t1
INNER JOIN applicable_rpm t2 ON t1.id = t2.mc_recordID
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

and the result are:

```
| machine_number |  rpm   |
---------------------------
|      MN-1      |  20    |
|      MN-2      | 20, 25 |
```

which is correct, but when i try on third table it duplicates it's value.

this my query:

```
SELECT t1.machine_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(' ', t2.speed) machine_speed,
       GROUP_CONCAT(' ', t3.twine) production_line
FROM machine_list t1
INNER JOIN applicable_rpm t2 ON t1.id = t2.mc_recordID
INNER JOIN applicable_product t3 ON t1.id = t3.mc_recordID
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

and the result are:

```
| machine_number |  rpm   |   twine    |
----------------------------------------
|      MN-1      | 20, 20 | mono, poly |
|      MN-2      | 20, 25 | mono, poly |
```

What should i do?

Comment: Those `machine_id`, `speed` and `twine` column names in your query can't be found in your example tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't group, you'll see there are two rows associated with MN-2. So if you group_concat it'll display the value for the selected column from both rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM machine_list t1
INNER JOIN applicable_rpm t2 ON t1.id = t2.mc_recordID
INNER JOIN applicable_product t3 ON t1.id = t3.mc_recordID;
```

You're going to need to use nested selects here. Something like the following:

```
SELECT machine_number, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(rpm) FROM applicable_rpm WHERE mc_recordID = t1.ID) as rpm,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(productline) FROM applicable_product WHERE mc_recordID = t1.ID) as twin,
    FROM machine_list t1;
```

As an after thought you could also try GROUP_CONCAT with DISTINCT

```
SELECT t1.machine_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.speed) machine_speed,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t3.twine) production_line
FROM machine_list t1
INNER JOIN applicable_rpm t2 ON t1.id = t2.mc_recordID
INNER JOIN applicable_product t3 ON t1.id = t3.mc_recordID
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

Comment: It works... i am new to sqLanguage, i didn't know that it was possible to nest a select command. Any ways thanks again...

Comment: @Tushar that would be my second option...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your join is producing duplicate rows.

We can achieve the desired output by making use of subqueries.

```
SELECT t1.machine_number, t2.machine_speed, t3.production_line
FROM machine_list t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT mc_recordID, GROUP_CONCAT(' ', speed) AS machine_speed
  FROM applicable_rpm
  GROUP BY mc_recordID
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.mc_recordID
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT mc_recordID, GROUP_CONCAT(' ', twine) AS production_line
  FROM applicable_product
  GROUP BY mc_recordID
) t3 ON t1.id = t3.mc_recordID;
```

This will return you the expected output :

| machine_number | machine_speed | production_line |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MN-1 | 20 | mono |
| MN-2 | 20, 25 | mono, poly |